# I want to learn how to use DYMOLA command window

Tags: modeling, modelica, openmodelica, dymola

How to use command window in Dymola as in MATLAB . I have a variable in a model file variable Name is "a" and other variable "b" i want to print the result like a*b in DYmola command window how to do this .Whenever I try I get undeclared variable message I want this to easily debug my model

i also want to know while running a model file can i write a print statement and see what is the value of that variable

Answer (score 3):

You are asking two different question here. Printing during a simulation has nothing to do with the command window. It requires to modify the code of a model before translation and it will print to the simulation log.

The command window on the other hand is decoupled from running simulations and has no access on model variables. It can be used to set start values, run simulations or create plots.

## Command Window

The command window in Dymola is rather limited, especially if you compare it with Matlab. In practice I hardly use it, because most things you do there can be done more conveniently in another way.

The table below lists some use cases and the alternatives to the command window:

| Feature | Example | Alternative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Set flags for translation, simulation, etc. | `OutputCPUtime=true` `Evaluate=true` `Advanced.AllowStringParameters=true` | Use Variable editor accessible via <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Variables</kbd> |
| Run simulation | `simulateModel("MyModel)` | Use buttons in GUI; keyboard shortcut <kbd>F10</kbd> |
| Change working directory | `cd C:/tmp` | Use <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Working Directory</kbd> |
| Set parameters and start values after translating a model | `translateModel("MyModel"); k=3; simulate` | Use edit fields in variable browser |
| Plot simulated variables | `createPlot(y={"J4.w"}`) | Use the GUI |
| Run external command | `$mkdir foo` | None, just do it outside of Dymola and get proper feedback (stdout and stderr are not accessible in Dymola) |

So as a summary, the command window is useful in a limited number of cases

1. for test purposes when you want to write Modelica scripts (`.mos` files)
2. to script simulations (see below)
3. to repeat a command dymola created in the command window (simulation, plot)

### Scripting simulations

The command window does not provide access to variables in models, neither the ones in the package browser, nor the last translated model or the one simulated. However, after you translate or simulate a model, the tunable parameters and start values can be set from the command window (I don't know a way of listing those variables, so you must know what variables exist  in the model available - or look at the variable browser, where you can also edit them).

Scripting works as follows:

1. translate a model: `translateModel("Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Examples.CoupledClutches")`
2. Set some start values: `f=0.5`, `T2=0.8`
3. Simulate the active model: `simulate`
4. Plot: `createPlot(y={"J4.w"}, grid=true)`

Next you could put those commands in a modelica script (.mos file) and do some parameter variations in a for loop. For more complex cases it is often easier to do the scripting outside of Dymola, e.g. in python with the python interface of Dymola.

## Printing

To print the value of a variable during simulation, use the function `Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print()`. The function only accepts strings as input, so you have to convert your values manually:

```
model PrintDemo
  import Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print;
  parameter String s="foo";
  Real r = 1/3;
  Integer i = 1;
  Boolean b = true;
initial equation
    print(s);
    print(String(r, format=".3f"));
    print(String(i));
    print(String(b));
end PrintDemo;
```

Simulate the model and it will print at simulation start the values to the simulation log. Of course you can also print during simulation, but in general it is adviced to limit the output to special events (using `when`, like `when time>0.5`). Otherwise you print for every time step, spamming the simulation log.

As you see the conversion is performed with the built-in function `String()`. For real values, the conversion format can be specified as described in [Chapter 3.6, operator 3.3 String](https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.6/operators-and-expressions.html#modelica:to-String) in the Modelica Specification.

Comment: This is pretty much a custom blog post answer, for a question that has no specifics and just a requirement. You're not answering any specific question. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. *How to use command window in Dymola as in MATLAB*: Accessing a "variable" is not straightforward as it changes over time. You should be able to access parameters (fixed for a simulation run) the way you are trying though. If you need to debug variables it is often the easiest to add the calculation for debugging to the model directly.
2. *Print variable*: The print-statement can be found here: `Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print`. Example uses can be found in `Modelica.Media.Examples.SolveOneNonlinearEquation.Inverse_sine` or `Modelica.Utilities.Examples.ReadRealMatrixFromFile`.